# How can I use a docker image saved as tar file in my Dockerfile as parent image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am saving my image to a tar file something like this

`docker save myimage:latest > myimage.tar.gz` and then I am trying to use this tar file in my Dockerfile like this

```
FROM scratch
ADD myimage.tar.gz
```

However the build is failing. Could someone please help me here how can I send tar file in Dockerfile

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `docker save` tarball, you need to [`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) it before it can be used.  When you do, that will print out the name(s) and tag(s) of the image(s) that were loaded.  You can then use that in the `FROM` line of your Dockerfile, like any other local image.

```sh
$ docker load -i myimage.tar.gz

Loaded image: my/image:and-its-tag
$ head -1 Dockerfile
FROM my/image:and-its-tag
```

If you `docker push` or `docker save` the resulting image, it will have a complete copy of the original image.

(In normal operation you shouldn't need `docker save`; prefer a registry service like Docker Hub, something cloud-hosted like GCR/ACR/ECR, or running your own.  You can't really directly use the saved image tarfile for anything.)

Comment: I don't want to do docker save and then use that.. I want to use .tar.gz way only to use as parent image

Answer (score 2):

For the fun - images are saved with the `manifest.json` which contains a list of images layers with the path to each `tar`'d layer. You can `ADD` the layers to a [`scratch` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch).

---

The `manifest.json` for the public `ubuntu:20.04` that is included in the `tar` file produced from a `docker save`:

```json
[
  {
    "Config": "4e2eef94cd6b93dd4d794c18b45c763f72edc22858e0da5b6e63a4566a54c03c.json",
    "RepoTags": [
      "ubuntu:20.04"
    ],
    "Layers": [
      "6d0f49bfc6be64bfab1f9c1fd2ed975f1b31300932f6e6a58431eba145aeef1f/layer.tar",
      "168251688b4a0d65c58c010d18c2e5e7bc7b1288e30e54f651e683fe7af5983c/layer.tar",
      "a48aad357767ae0e674c26ed749956078c003949bcd931af931dfc272cc96a9c/layer.tar",
      "a9d70cfea3838f5442dce79f10ea881c4705f3bbc1123a73317f90d0958341fb/layer.tar"
    ]
  }
]
```

... the layers can be added to a new image built `FROM scratch`:

```docker
FROM scratch
ADD 6d0f49bfc6be64bfab1f9c1fd2ed975f1b31300932f6e6a58431eba145aeef1f/layer.tar /
ADD 168251688b4a0d65c58c010d18c2e5e7bc7b1288e30e54f651e683fe7af5983c/layer.tar /
ADD a48aad357767ae0e674c26ed749956078c003949bcd931af931dfc272cc96a9c/layer.tar /
ADD a9d70cfea3838f5442dce79f10ea881c4705f3bbc1123a73317f90d0958341fb/layer.tar /
ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

> **Note**: setting the `CMD` and `ENV` from the parent image - the config is available in the file referenced by the `manifest.json`'s `Config` key.

[image: docker build from layers]

... if we `docker inspect` the image and compare it with the original, the layers are nearly identical:

[image: docker inspect image hackity-hack-hack]

... the last layer in the case of the `ubuntu:20.04` image contains the [`/run/systemd/container` config](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/7145f9723125e6e4367dc0fb428ffd9f2bc00334/focal/Dockerfile#L41) - the files `md5sum` in the built image is identical to that of the original image however the layer hash differs - the image history which is otherwise preserved in the config file is lost (the history is complete if you start `FROM ubuntu:20.04`, extend the image, save it, untar the file and inspect the config).

[image: /run/systemd/container checksum]

Can extend the `docker image` however you want:

```docker
FROM scratch
ADD 6d0f49bfc6be64bfab1f9c1fd2ed975f1b31300932f6e6a58431eba145aeef1f/layer.tar \
    168251688b4a0d65c58c010d18c2e5e7bc7b1288e30e54f651e683fe7af5983c/layer.tar \
    a48aad357767ae0e674c26ed749956078c003949bcd931af931dfc272cc96a9c/layer.tar \
    a9d70cfea3838f5442dce79f10ea881c4705f3bbc1123a73317f90d0958341fb/layer.tar /
ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends cowsay && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apt/lists/*
CMD ["cowsay"]
```

[image: docker cowsay hello world]

Comment: I am getting "ERROR: duplicates of file paths not supported" when trying to import the image this way.